# Sql get latest n rows in sql whose sum is greater than or equal to a value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table  of fb_data of following data

```
id sessions created_at

1   25     2020-05-28 12:00:00

2   30     2020-05-28 13:00:00

3   24     2020-05-29 14:00:00
```

I want to get latest rows whose sum creates greater than 40 . For e.g  id 2 and 3 creates the sum greater than 40   . Then I want only 2 and 3 rows excluding the rows 1

Comment: What would be wrong with using rows 1 and 2 to meet the requirement?

Comment: Because I want latest data that creates the sum

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Mysql version 8.0

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then honestly the easiest way is to use analytic functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(sessions) OVER (ORDER BY created_at DESC) sum_sessions
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT t1.id, t1.sessions, t1.created_at
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE t1.created_at >= (SELECT MAX(t2.created_at) FROM cte t2
                        WHERE t2.sum_sessions > 40);
```

Here is what the intermediate result defined in the CTE looks like:

```
id | sessions | created_at          | sum_sessions
1  | 25       | 2020-05-28 12:00:00 | 79
2  | 30       | 2020-05-28 13:00:00 | 54   <-- most recent date having required sum
3  | 24       | 2020-05-29 14:00:00 | 24
```

The subquery used in the `WHERE` clause of my query finds the *greatest* date on which a cumulative sum starting with the most recent date in the table was greater than 40.  Then, we simply select as few records going up to that date.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sum of sessions for each row with `SUM()` window function.
So you need all the rows which have sum minus their value of `sessions` less (or equal?) than 40:

```
SELECT id, sessions, created_at
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(sessions) OVER (ORDER BY created_at DESC) - sessions total
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE total < 40
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uqkpqkMCJaJybrRwnwsT3j/1).
Results:

```
| id  | sessions | created_at          |
| --- | -------- | ------------------- |
| 3   | 24       | 2020-05-29 14:00:00 |
| 2   | 30       | 2020-05-28 13:00:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
select * from (select *,sum(session_name) OVER (ORDER BY Id)x from t1 ) a where x>40
```